# Scipy Linear Programming with Slack Variable

Tags: python, scipy, linear-programming

I would like to minimize an objective function which I calculate based on variables `A, B1, B2, B3, B4` coming from 4 `Center`s.

My (simplified) dataset looks like follows:

```
    Center1  Center2  Center3  Center4
A   10.0000  10.0000  10.0000  10.0000
B1   0.8415   0.9547   0.9460   0.9512
B2   0.9895   0.9443   0.9042   0.9634
B3   0.9460   0.9443   0.8101   0.9199
B4   0.9878   0.8362   0.9233   0.7909
```

I know how to find the vector of weights `x` that minimizes this objective function simply using [scipy.optimize.linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog
from numpy.linalg import multi_dot as dot
import pandas as pd

# minimise the costs across A and B variables in the 4 centres.
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[10, 10, 10, 10],
                           [0.8415, 0.9547, 0.9460, 0.9512],
                           [0.9895, 0.9443, 0.9042, 0.9634],
                           [0.9460, 0.9443, 0.8101, 0.9199],
                           [0.9878, 0.8362, 0.9233, 0.7909]]),
                  columns=['Center1', 'Center2', 'Center3', 'Center4'],
                  index=['A', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'])
# to reduce df (2-D array) to a 1-D array
lamb = np.array([0.1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
bounds = list(zip([-3, -3, -3, -3], [3, 3, 3, 3]))
A= None
b=None
c = dot([lamb,df.values]).squeeze()
res3 = linprog(c=c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=bounds,
              options={"disp": True})
# Solution vector of weights x
x = res3.x
```

My question is, I want to penalize the max difference between `B1.x, B2.x, B3.x, B4.x`. In other words, at the end of the optimization, I want the solution set `x` that results in the [least absolute deviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Least_absolute_deviations&action=edit&section=6) in set `B1.x, B2.x, B3.x, B4.x`.

```
>>df.loc[['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'],:].dot(x)
Out[24]: 
B1   -11.0802
B2   -11.4042
B3   -10.8609
B4   -10.6146
dtype: float64
```

I can calculate the pairwise differences between all pairs of `Bi,Bj` as follows, since I want the maximum differences for each pair I look at both `Bi-Bj` and `Bj-Bi`.

```
# pairwise differences
constraints = {'b1_b2' : df.loc['B1']-df.loc['B2'],
               'b1_b3' : df.loc['B1']-df.loc['B3'],
               'b1_b4' : df.loc['B1']-df.loc['B4'],
               'b2_b3' : df.loc['B2']-df.loc['B3'],
               'b2_b4' : df.loc['B2']-df.loc['B4'],
               'b3_b4' : df.loc['B3']-df.loc['B4']}
const_df = pd.DataFrame(constraints)
A = pd.concat([const_df, -1*const_df], axis=1).T
b = np.array([1]*12) # the 1's here are arbitrary place holders.
res4 = linprog(c=c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=bounds,
          options={"disp": True})
```

The code above runs but I do not quite get how to include slack variables that penalise the `max()` of these pairwise differences in `A`, which are currently just in `Ax<=b` constraint form. I am aware Linear Programming can be used to solve the absolute deviation problem. I would appreciate greatly if anyone can provide some direction / simple code.

Comment: Maybe add a formal description of your optimization-problem as it's not your typical LP-problem (no constraints?) and it's questionable if that's the approach to take here. Penalizing the differences to each other in LP is possible, but only with l1-norm (which has some downsides). L2-norm like penalization would render it a QP (not available in scipy). If your problem is really constraint-less, there is not need to use linprog. scipy's minimize then would be much easier to use and can work with nonlinear objectives (e.g. l2-norm).

Comment: @sascha, thank you for your comment. I have been told it is possible to penalize all C (4,2) pairs using pairwise differences `(B1-B2), (B1-B3),...` and including slack variables and a maximum deviation variable. So solving this while remaining within LP. I just do not know how to formulate it exactly.

Comment: Yes it's possible and can be done easier with auxiliary-variables. But i'm not sold yet about it being a good approach.

Comment: @sascha, there are indeed other inequality constraints but I have excluded them to simplify the problem to capture the core of my question: use of slack variables and minimizing the "variance" in the `B1.x, B2.x, B3.x, B4.x`.

Comment: Completely ignoring things like that does not help much (as people will question your approach). Research / decide on the penalization first: l1, l2, ... It's not yet formal in a mathematical sense.

Comment: @sascha, I guess what I am trying to achieve is to penalise the magnitude, in that sense it is L1 but instead of `constraint = abs(a)<3`, we could write `constaint_lower = -3<=a` and `constraint_upper= a<=3` to make it LP-compliant. I am just not sure how to formulate it in the API.

Answer (score 1):

Minimizing the range of a set of variables is not too difficult:

```
minimize sum(j, c(j)*x(j)) + P*(maxx - minx)
B(i) = sum(j, b(i,j)*x(j))
minx ≤ B(i)
maxx ≥ B(i)
```

where `minx` and `maxx` are additional variables and `p` is some penalty. This is linear and continuous so can be used in an LP model in a straightforward way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am not clear on how to implement what you provide above in the context of linear programming. Some more context would be helpful.

Comment: You don't know how to add a linear constraint to an LP?

Comment: I know how to a dd a linear constraint. I do not know which columns you propose to add to `C` in `C'x`, which is `df` in my example.

Comment: You need to add variables (or columns) `B1`,`B2`,`B3`.`B4` and `minx`,`maxx` to your LP problem.

Comment: Apologies, I have edited my question to try to make it clearer.

Comment: No need for pairwise differences in my opinion, But if you really want to go that route you need to use an absolute deviation formulation. This is not very difficult either and explained in any book on linear programming.

Comment: Would you mind demonstrating the solution you propose with the code example I give? Is ti doable using just the `linprog` function I give?

Comment: Yes it is doable. I suggest to first write down your problem in mathematical notation. Once the mathematical model makes sense, then try to transcribe it into a form required by the solver.